# HttpInterceptor with observable 'intercept' in type 'AuthenticationInterceptor' is not > same property in base type 'HttpInterceptor'

Tags: angular, angular-http, rxjs6

I don't understand what's wrong with this code
can you help me, please ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationSharedStorage } from '../storages/authentication.storage';
import { AuthenticationToken } from '../../models/authentication.model';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private storage: AuthenticationSharedStorage) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    this.storage.getData()
    .pipe(
      switchMap((data:AuthenticationToken )=> {
      if(data){
        const authToken = data.token;
        const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: authToken } });
        return next.handle(authReq);
      }
      return next.handle(req);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The complete error is:

> Property 'intercept' in type 'AuthenticationInterceptor' is not
>   assignable to the same property in base type 'HttpInterceptor'. Type
>   '(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler) => void' is not assignable
>   to type '(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler) =>
>   Observable>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable>'. 16:3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return an `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` from `intercept` - currently nothing is returned.  Assuming `this.storage.getData()` returns one (likely true since it has `pipe()`) then just put a return before it.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  return this.storage.getData()
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error, the problem caused by the difference in rxjs version between project and npm package.

I Fix this issue by installing the same version of rxjs in the project.